# Dispatch action from componentWillUnmount()

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-context, use-reducer

I am creating a Multi part form as below,

```
<Parent>
 <FormPart1 />
 <FormPart2 />
 <Button />
</Parent>
```

I am trying to get **FormPart1** value in **Parent** when clicking **Button**.

For this I am using dispatch from within **componentWillUnmount()** phase.

I this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would probably be to have your state (for both **FormPart1** and **FormPart2**) reside in the **Parent** component in the first place.

If you still need to preserve your initial approach, dispatching the state within the **componentWillUnmount** lifecycle method is okay.

Maybe a more natural approach would be to have an **onClick** handle for the **Button** and dispatch the state there (right before unmounting the **FormPart** component and mounting the other one).

This way you have more control and can even validate the first form before the user can continue to the other.